# Updating useState without inserting another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, use-state

This is the full code of the component, I am so tired that I can't think much on how to solve this problem

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


function CnContent(props) {
    const getCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    const products = [
        {
            id: 0,
            imgsrc: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/images/products/grocery-staples/pro_1.jpg',
            name: "O'range 500 ml Coconut Oil(Bottle)",
            quantity: "500 ml",
            offer_price: "₹ 116",
            real_price: "₹ 219",
            inCart: 1
        },

        {
            id: 1,
            imgsrc: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/images/products/grocery-staples/pro_2.jpg',
            name: "Parachute 100% Pure Coconut Oil (Plastic Bottle)",
            quantity: "600 ml",
            offer_price: "₹ 210",
            real_price: "₹ 250",
            inCart: 1
        },

        {
            id: 2,
            imgsrc: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/images/products/grocery-staples/pro_3.jpg',
            name: "Fortune Soya Chunks",
            quantity: "1 kg",
            offer_price: "₹ 126",
            real_price: "₹ 135",
            inCart: 1
        },
    ]
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(getCart);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    }, [cart])
    function addToCart(pr) {
        let duplicate = cart.find((x) => x.id === pr.id)

        if (!duplicate) {
            setCart((prevState) => {
                return [...prevState, pr]
            });
        }
        else {
            setCart((prevState) => [...prevState, prevState[pr.id] = { inCart: prevState[pr.id].inCart + 1 }]); // This creates another object and sends to the array (cart), but I want to change the value of the specific product(cart[pr.id]).
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className='cn-table'>
                <div className='section-left'></div>
                <div className='section-right'>

                    {
                        products.map((pr, i) => {
                            return (
                                <div tabIndex='-1' className='products' key={i}>
                                    <div className="products__wrapper">
                                        <Link to='https://www.youtube.com' className='products__link'>
                                            <div className='products__img'>
                                                <img src={pr.imgsrc} alt={pr.name}></img>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='products__name'>{pr.name}</div>
                                            <div className='products__quantity'>{pr.quantity}</div>
                                        </Link>
                                        <div className='products__details'>
                                            <div className='products__details__price'>
                                                <div className='products__details__price__offer'>{pr.offer_price}</div>
                                                <div className='products__details__price__real'>{pr.real_price}</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='add-to-cart zero-products'>
                                                <button className='add-to-cart__remove' >-</button>
                                                <button className='add-to-cart__text active'>{pr.inCart}</button>
                                                <button className='add-to-cart__add' onClick={() => addToCart(pr)}>+</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export { CnContent };
```

These are results of localStorage value, the problem is instead of changing the value of inCart of the specific object, it's creating a new object with property "inCart".

```
0: {id: 0, pr_category: "grocery-staples", imgsrc: "/assets/images/products/grocery-staples/pro_1.jpg",…}
1: {id: 1, pr_category: "grocery-staples", imgsrc: "/assets/images/products/grocery-staples/pro_2.jpg",…}
2: {inCart: 1} /*Instead of this new object I want to change the value in the upper objects*/
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you !

EDIT: Changed the value of inCart from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `map` over the cart and update only the product you want

```js
setCart((prevState) => prevState.map(product=>{
   if (product.id === pr.id) {
    return {
      ...product,
      inCart: product.inCart + 1
    }
   }
   return product;
});
```

Comment: It  works if the localStorage has already some value in it, but it doesn't work if the localStorage is empty. Thanks for the hardwork.

Comment: @ANURAGGOLDEN this is for the `else` part. Your case where no duplicate exists works fine.

Comment: aslo your `getCart` should be initialized like `const getCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];` to have a default value when localStorage is not set up yet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I also have a Header component which has duty to give 'cart' item to the localStorage if it does not have any.

Comment: Oh wait let me try

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved this code if I change the value of inCart from 0 to 1, but if possible post an answer where I don't have change the value of inCart.

```
function addToCart(pr) {
    setCart((prevState) => {
        let duplicate = prevState.find((x) => x.id === pr.id)
        if (!duplicate)
            return [...prevState, pr];
        else {
            prevState[pr.id].inCart += 1;
            return [...prevState];
        }
    })
}
```

I have use this code above instead of:

```
function addToCart(pr) {
     let duplicate = cart.find((x) => x.id === pr.id)

     if (!duplicate) {
         setCart((prevState) => {
         return [...prevState, pr]
         });
     }
     else {
          setCart((prevState) => [...prevState, prevState[pr.id] = { inCart: prevState[pr.id].inCart + 1 }]); // This creates another object and sends to the array (cart), but I want to change the value of the specific product(cart[pr.id]).
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will also affect the `product` array as you are mutating the object.

Comment: nope, the product array is constant and I am not mutating it at all. I have used map function to create a temporary object which loops and gets terminated

Comment: The code that does `prevState[pr.id].inCart += 1;` mutates the `products` as well becuase in the cart you insert elements through  `addToCart(pr)` where `pr` is an object. So the cart references the product items. The array is constant but you mutate the objects inside it that way.

Comment: Oh yes I am mutating the object, not the array. I had no choice as I didn't wanted to create another object in the `localStorage` if I want to increase the no of same products. So I thought I should mutate the value of inCart of the specific Object `pr.id`

Comment: I am going to ask another question. It **is** a silly question but if you help me with that plz do.

Comment: This is the title```How to give `this` the value of caller Object that is an array
```

Comment: not sure i understand.  Can you give an example where you would use `this` in that way ?